# in bootstrap table how to hide/exclude a column on export

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using the attribute  data-show-export ="true" but i dont know how to exclude a column using jQuery ,
i have tried,

```
$('table').bootstrapTable({     
  exportOptions: {
    columns: [0,1]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data-force-hide attribute as "true" in table head where you define your table column. follow the belows table head.

```
<th data-field="action"
    data-align="center"
    data-formatter="actionFormatter"
    data-events="actionEvents"
    data-force-hide="true">Action</th>
```

You may also use your bootstrap-table without attribute,like jquery calling. there you can also forcefully hide your desire columns by used forceHide: true property where you define your columns. like

```js
$('table').bootstrapTable({ 
columns: [ {
        title: 'Action',
        field: 'Action',
        visible: true,
        sortable: false,
        align: "center",
        formatter: "actionFormatterSubGrid",
        events: "actionEventsSubGrid",
       forceHide: true, /* You have to need use this property*/
    }
    , {
        title: 'ID',
        field: 'id',
        visible: false,
        sortable: true,
        forceExport: true,  /* And use this for forcefully export hidden columns*/
    }],

    showExport: true,    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit older question, but, for some people with this doubt, on exportOptions, use ignoreColumn: ["Column"], this will hide column when export.

**Example:**

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    pagination: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    pageList: [15, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 'ALL'],
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Id",
            field: "Id"
        },  
        {
            title: "Company",
            field: "Company"
        },
    ],
 exportOptions: {
        ignoreColumn: ["Id"]
    }
});
```